# 1px border issue for img

Tags: html, css, border

So I am having an issue with 1px border for `img`. They have a strange distance between them and it becomes even worse when scaling (see codepen). I don’t have any idea where it is coming from and how to fix it.

My HTML:

```
<article class="comment">
    <div class="comment__image-block">
      <img class="comment__img" src="https://i.imgur.com/dSEAOsy.jpg" alt="Avatar" title="Avatar">
    </div>
  </article>
```

My SCSS:

```
 .comment {
  &__image-block {
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:before {
      content: ' ';
      display: block;
      background-color: white;
      width: 60%;
      height: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      right: -11px;
      top: -2px;
      outline: 1px solid red;
      transform: skewX(53deg);
    }
  }
  &__img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/kolarus/pen/yqOgeG)

Image:

[image]

Comment: remove `content: ' ';` from  `&:before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I fixed your problem by changing a part of your code to this:

```
&__img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

I hope it will work for you! Maybe there is a better way, because in this case the border is placed on the edge of the image, but I do not know the other way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this does not help match, issue is still present even with `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @BogdanMorozov that is strange, as for me it works, at least in your codepen sample and using google chrome...

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome the issue is resolved. In Firefox there wasn't even a problem to begin with (for me at least).

Comment: In Microsoft Edge the issue is also resolved for me.

Comment: Latest version of chrome

Comment: @BogdanMorozov Could it be cache? I doubt it, but who knows? Try to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same issue with my image:

```
.overlay-item img {
    width: 568px;
    height: 253px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

The fix was to add `1px` more of width and `box-sizing: border-box;`, since without this 1 more pixel, the border didn't stick to the left instead of the right. Really peculiar behavior.

```
.overlay-item img {
    width: 569px;
    height: 253px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```